# GetOrCreate in RavenDB, or a better alternative?

Tags: ravendb

I have just started using RavenDB on a personal project and so far inserting, updating and querying have all been very easy to implement. However, I have come across a situation where I need a GetOrCreate method and I'm wondering what the best way to achieve this is.

Specifically I am integrating with OpenID and once authentication has taken place the user is redirected to my site. At this point I'd either like to retrieve their user record from Raven (by querying on the ClaimsIdentifier property) or create a new record. The user's ID is currently being set by Raven.

Obviously I can write this in two statements but without some sort of transaction around the select and the create I could potentially end up with two user records in the database with the same claims identifier.

Is there anyway to achieve this kind of functionality? Possibly even more importantly is do you think I'm going down the wrong path. I'm assuming even if I could create a transaction it would make scaling out to multiple servers difficult and in anycase could add a performance bottle-neck.

Would a better approach be to have the Query and Create operations as separate statements and check for duplicates when the user is retrieved and merge at that point. Or do something similar but on a scheduled task?

I can't help but feel I'm missing something obvious here so any advice on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Note: while scaling out to multiple servers may seem unnessecary for a personal project, I'm using it as an evaluation of Raven before using it in work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dan, although RavenDB has support for transactions, I wouldn't go that way in your case. Instead, you could just use the users ClaimsIdentifier as the user documents id, because they are granted to be unique.

Alternatively, you can also stay with user ids being generated by Raven (HiLo btw) and use the new UniqueConstraintsBundle, which lets you attribute certain properties to be unique. Internally it will create an additional document that has the value of your unique property as its id.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that UniqueConstraintBundle looks interesting and once it's pulled into the main project I definitely try using it. I think you're right though, in this can I can probably just make the claimsidentifier the ID. Cheers